# Неправильно перенесся сайт с локального сервера на удаленный

Tags: php, wordpress, сервер

Вот так у меня выглядит сайт на локальном сервере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так после переноса на удаленный
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заливал через FileZilla

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы. Я вам уже ответил - сносите все нафиг и переносите плагином Duplicator

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [После загрузки на сервер появляется ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Написал подробно о переносе сайта : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220

Answer (score 0):

Предположение -->  у вас в коде некоторые пути к CSS файлам прописаны абсолютно.

Итого по факту сайт не видит CSS и у вас слетела шапка, менюха и соц. кнопки.

Решение -->   проверить доступность CSS файлов на хостинге.